# How to use Android Tablet emulator?

Tags: android

I want to start android tablet application development. i have created a new avd with 1024X600 emulator and launched, but how to come back from emulator when i click any application? is there any specific api available for developing android tablet applications or can we use the same android api for development.

Please help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll use the same APIs for tablets.

At least this is what I have known till now.

You may get emulator skins for some tablets if their manufacturers are providing them as add-ons

In the new SDK released with Gingerbread, you get an option to download the add-on of Samsung Galaxy Tab, which will give you the emulator skin and feel of the Galaxy tab.
try that out.

Comment: HI,When  i want to upgrade Android Gingerbread to my Eclipse, i have followed some steps from internet,
1) Android SDK and AVD Manager, then Available packages, but if i click respository.xml file, it is giving this error

    Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/reposi ... sitory.xml, reason: dl-ssl.google.com. 

.  Please help and guide me ?

Comment: The SDK Manager that you have is old now. Considering that you're on windows, go to developer docs, and download the new SDK Manager from Download section, there is a .exe file specially for windows. Install it. Now go to your eclipse, update the path to android SDK, and point eclipse to new SDK. Now update the ADT by Eclipse's update option. Now, Go to your old SDK folder, copy all the things from 'platforms' folder inside it, and paste them inside 'platforms' folder of new SDK directory this makes you have your old platforms back. Run the SDK Manager and Update from repository.

Comment: Do comment back if you jump into any problems

Comment: Hey Thanks for the guiding me, i have installed the new sdk and tablet emulator also,i have created a new tablet emulator with 1024x600 size. it was created,but once i click any folder how can i get back from that folder ? Please help

Comment: use the ESC key on ur keyboard to close perform the same action that the 'back' button provides

Answer (score 2):

Just update SDK Manager. Android 3.0 (API 11) is custom made for tablets. you dont even need to change the resolution.