# Start ICS emulator without Menu button

Tags: android, menu, android-emulator, android-actionbar

I'm trying to see the overflow menu in the ActionBar on ICS and I don't have a device.

I'm using the emulator and want to know, how do I start the emulator without a Menu button?  I want to emulate a device with no Menu hardware button.

I've looked on:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html but I don't see how to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you updated your SDK to API11 or higher？ This maybe help you. [how-to-use-android-tablet-emulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435889/how-to-use-android-tablet-emulator

Comment: I'm updated using API14 (ICS) using tools version 15

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, so just the next day Reto Meier posted on G+ that the new tools (version 16) have an option in the emulator that allows you to set in the Hardware section:

Hardware Back/Home keys

If you set this to no then you get the overflow menu in the ActionBar.

[image]

Comment: To add this option start the AVD manager. Select the avd and click the edit button. Under hardware select new. In the Property scroll down list select the option shown above, Hardware Back/Home keys. Press okay and then edit the value in the Hardware list as shown above.