# Virtual device without menu button

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I found this answer: "[Start ICS emulator without Menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468810/start-ics-emulator-without-menu-button)" but the "hardware" properties list doesn't exist in the latest AVD manager GUI (v21.1).

How to create an ICS emulator without menu button in the latest version (21.1) of AVD manager ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new-version UI, you must go to the `Device Definitions` tab (inside the `Android Virtual Device Manager` window) to configure the virtual hardware.  Once you've set up a device definition the way you like it, you can `Create AVD...` from that definition.

Comment: I've already created my own device definition but couldn't figure out how to remove the menu button. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: You can set "Buttons" to either "hardware" or "software".  Software buttons does not include a menu button.  You may still see it in your emulator skin (if enabled) but it is non-functional.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new device under "device definitions", there you can set several settings. Then create an avd based on your custom device.